# How to Add a map Value to an array in firestore Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I am pretty new to firebase and swift. I have my FireStore DB like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzpOL.png). I want to add map values *Reply* and *userID* to **Replies** and every time I add new map value, it should append to **Replies** array on next Index. I know that ***updateDocument*** function will be used here, but I don't have the slightest idea of how to use that. Kindly guide me in any way possible. Thanks! Below is the sample code

```
@IBAction func replyPressed(_ sender: DesignableButton) {

    let db = Firestore.firestore().document("\(Path!)/All Reviews/\(docID!)")
    let replyDictionary = ["UserID": userID!, "Reply":ReplytextField.text!]

    db.updateData(/*No hint about that*/ ) { (error) in

        if error ! = nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            print("Posted")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try using the `replyDictionary` you've created?

Comment: sorry @Frankenstein i didn't get you. I will use `replyDictionary` in here, but I don't know how to put that on a first or second index under `Replies` array.

Comment: What is this `Replies` array? How is it defined and what is it used for?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, `Replies` is an array of map inside document where a user will post the review. To make it simple, A user will post a review about some property, and then someone else can reply to that review, so the `reply` and persons `userID` will be obtained and then that will make the `replyDictionary` and that will be in turn appended to `Replies` array. RN, I haven't coded that array. The one present in picture is just for guidance

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use FieldValue.arrayUnion for that.

```
let db = Firestore.firestore().document("\(Path!)/All Reviews/\(docID!)")
let replyDictionary = ["UserID": userID!, "Reply":ReplytextField.text!]

db.updateData(["name_of_your_array" : FieldValue.arrayUnion([replyDictionary])]) { (error) in

        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please explain what your code does, otherwise most people will be able to learn of your answer more than "user it & forget it".

Comment: **Hi**, we can use union of arrays. It works nice. You don't need to download your array on a client and then update all array with included data However if you have the same map that have been already downloaded to firestore you don't have a duplicate on your database. This could be very helpful: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array